# dyplr multiple filters to update derived field. Group error to mutate derived field. group_by %>% mutate | filter %>% mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, mutate

**Problem**

Need to add new computed column to existing data.frame. That is the easy part: mutate and assign. Now I have a categorical column that has 8 categories, for each, I need to assign a filtered set of rows to compute the death rate for that scope of population rows.

Group Error.

The idea solution is to process separate unique categories, e.g, injury death mechanism. Each category group is to be assigned via filtered age groups.

The data has 5 age groups and 10 category injury death mechanisms (data example below). For each separate age groups and each separate injury death mechanism, need to have a computed death rate per this scope (death/population). My filter on the age group uses grep method for this factorized age group.

The basic setup for the age groups, repeated for each age group. The following for just age 15; need to process of all 5 age groups and subprocess each separate injury death mechanism, and compute derived rate. Right now I have separate specific code line one for each age group.

```
df_age_1524 <- df_age_1524 %>%
  group_by(Injury.mechanism) %>%
  mutate(AgeGrp.DRate <- df_age_1524$Deaths / df_age_1524$Population * 1000 * 100)

df_age_2544 <- df_age_2544 %>%
  group_by(Injury.mechanism) %>%
  mutate(AgeGrp.DRate <- df_age_2544$Deaths / df_age_2544$Population * 1000 * 100)
```

** Error **

```
> df_age_2544 <- df_age_2544 %>%
+   group_by(Injury.mechanism) %>%
+   mutate(AgeGrp.DRate <- df_age_2544$Deaths / df_age_2544$Population * 1000 * 100)
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `AgeGrp.DRate <- ...`.
ℹ In group 1: `Injury.mechanism = All Mechanisms`.
Caused by error:
! `AgeGrp.DRate <- ...` must be size 216 or 1, not 2376.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

```
df_age_15 <- df_age_15 %>%
  mutate(AgeGrp.DRate = 0)

df_age_15 <- df_suicide_data %>%
  filter(grepl('15', as.character(Age.Group)))
...
...
```

In this code, I am attempting to setup a mutate of age group for death rate by 1) filtered age 15, 2) grouped by injury.mechanism, mutate AgeGrp.DRate. This was a promising short approach. But it did not work as needed. No AgeGrp.DRate was updated.

```
df_age_15 <- df_age_15 %>%
  group_by(Injury.mechanism) %>%
    mutate(AgeGrp.DRate <- df_age_15$Deaths / df_age_15$Population * 1000 * 100)
...
...
... repeated for each age group, and grouped by Injury.mechanism
```

In this code, I am attempting to setup a mutate of age group for death rate by 1) filtered for specific injury.mechanism (there are 10 to perform same, then mutate AgeGrp.DRate. In this code, only the filter() executed. Mutate did not execute.

```
df_age_15 <- df_age_15 %>%
  filter(grepl('Cut', as.character(Injury.mechanism))) #%>% 
    mutate(AgeGrp.DRate <- df_age_15$Deaths / df_age_15$Population * 1000 * 100)

df_age_15 %>%
  filter(grepl('Drwn', as.character(Injury.mechanism))) #%>% 
    mutate(AgeGrp.DRate <- df_age_15$Deaths / df_age_15$Population * 1000 * 100)
...
...
... repeated for each age group and each Injury.Mechanisms Levels: All Mechanisms, Cut, Drwn, Fall, Hot, Firearm, OT, Poison, Unspecified, Suff, All Other Specified
```

**Data Example for Problem logic**

```
Age.Group Levels: < 15, 15–24, 25–44, 45–64, 65–74, 75+, All Ages
Injury.Mechanisms Levels All Mechanisms, Cut, Drwn, Fall, Hot, Firearm, OT, Poison, Unspecified, Suff, All Other Specified
```

Comment: There are actuarial and demography packages. Questions that have vague descriptions without real solid examples are often ignored and eventually closed.

Comment: Try `mutate(col_name =...) ` instead of `mutate(col_name <-...) `

Comment: The error message is indicating that the assignment chain in the mutate function (AgeGrp.DRate <- df_age_2544$Deaths / df_age_2544$Population * 1000 * 100) is returning a vector of length 2376, which is not same as with the size of the column being created (expected size is 216, one value per group)... To fix the error you are getting, you should first use the `mutate()` function with `summarise()` to calculate the summary statistics by group (in your case, basically the `mean`) and then assign the result to the new column in the original dataframe.

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post accordingly.